# Find all regions where this function is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let:
$$ f(z) = \left| x^2-y^2 \right| + 2i\left|xy\right|, \; z = x + iy$$
How to find all regions where $f$ is holomorphic? I suppose it has something to do with dividing $\mathbb C$ into eight regions. For example, if $x > y > 0$ then $f(z) = z^2$. Is there an easier way than just calculating: $$\frac{\partial f }{\partial{\bar{z}}} = 0\,?$$

Comment: The real and imaginary parts of a holomorphic function must be smooth. Where are the real and imaginary parts of the given function $f$ not smooth?

Comment: Actually you can reduce to $4$ regions, by applying symmetry $(x,y)\to (-x,-y).$

Comment: When you cross the $y=x$ line from where $f(z) = z^2$, the real part of $f(z)$ changes signs, while the imaginary part does not. So it becomes $f(z) = -\overline{z^2}$. Is that still holomorphic? If you then cross $y=0$, the imaginary part changes signs. ...

Answer (score 1):

HINT: The criterion of CR-equations along with the continuity condition of $u,v,u_x,v_x,u_y$ and $v_y$ holds on $\mathbb C-\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2| y=\pm x, y=0, x=0\}$.